# What is the correct way to form a parameterized SQL statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, parameterized-query

**Objective:** Using C# and SQL2008 correctly setup a Parameterized SQL Insert statement

**Issue:** The following statement is used in a for loop so the values must be cleared. Upon running this code it states there is a syntax error near 250. The code is as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    struct Row = (struct)Rows[i];

    sql = "@RowName varchar(250) = null " +
    "INSERT INTO " +
        "database.dbo.table" +
             "(database.dbo.tabe.RowName) " +
    "VALUES " +
        "(@RowName) ";

 cmd.CommandText = sql;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowValue ", Row.RowName);
```

}

Thank you in advance for corrections, comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to re-declare the variable inside the SQL code. This should work:

```
sql =
    "INSERT INTO " +
        "database.dbo.table" +
            "(database.dbo.tabe.RowName) " +
    "VALUES " +
        "(@RowName) ";

cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowValue ", Row.RowName);
```

Answer (score 2):

`struct` is a keyword, you can't use it as a type name. You don't need to declare the parameter first, (all necessary metadata is inferred from `AddWithValue` in this case) and the parameter name in the SQL query has to match what you put in `AddWithValue`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    var Row = (MyStruct)Rows[i];

    sql = "INSERT INTO " +
        "database.dbo.table " +
             "(database.dbo.tabe.RowName) " +
    "VALUES " +
        "(@RowName)";

    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowName", Row.RowName);
}
```