# Value not passing When return json value in return view

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i have one view and i want to return json value in view i am using this way but data not return . when remove return view and only pass return json () then data show in grid . but not in correct format means data show like console windows not properly display in jqgrid. i am sharing Action Result and json function and Grid which i am using .

kindly review this and tell me what is solution How can i return json value in return view .

```
Action

    public ActionResult Ownership_Detail(string MemberShipID)
                {
                    ViewBag.id = MemberShipID;
                    Ownership_D(MemberShipID);
                    return View(Json(ViewBag.objOwnershipDetail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));


                }



json Function
     public JsonResult Ownership_D(string MemberShipID)
            {
                List<OwnerShip> OwnerShipDetail = new List<OwnerShip>();
                OwnerShip obj_ownership;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
                {
                    if (MemberShipID == null)
                    {
                        cmd = new SqlCommand("select ISNULL(FD.FileID, '') as FileID, FD.TransDate, P.PhaseName as Project, CONCAT(RTRIM(Sec.SectorName), +'/' + I.PlotNo) as UnitNo,RP.RPersonName " +
                           "from MemberMaster MM " +
                           "inner join MembersDetail MD on MD.MemberShipID = MM.MemberShipID and MD.Srno = 1 " +
                           "inner join MasterFileDetail FD on FD.MembershipID = MM.MemberShipID and FD.IsOwner = 1 and FD.IsTransfered = 1 and FD.IsCancelled=0 " +
                           "inner join MasterFile FM on FM.FileID = FD.FileID and FM.Cancel = 0 " +
                           "inner join Sectors Sec on Sec.Phase_ID = FM.PhaseId and Sec.Sector_ID = FM.Sector_ID " +
                           "left join PlotsInventory I on I.Phase_ID = FM.PhaseId and I.Plot_ID = FM.Plot_ID " +
                           "inner join Phases P on P.Phase_ID = FM.PhaseId " +
                           "inner join ReferencePerson RP on RP.RPersonID = FM.RPersonID " +
                           "where MM.MemberShipID = '" + clsCommon._MembershipID + "'", con);
                }

                    else
                    {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("select ISNULL(FD.FileID, '') as FileID, FD.TransDate, P.PhaseName as Project, CONCAT(RTRIM(Sec.SectorName), +'/' + I.PlotNo) as UnitNo,RP.RPersonName " +
                             "from MemberMaster MM " +
                             "inner join MembersDetail MD on MD.MemberShipID = MM.MemberShipID and MD.Srno = 1 " +
                             "inner join MasterFileDetail FD on FD.MembershipID = MM.MemberShipID and FD.IsOwner = 1 and FD.IsTransfered = 1 and FD.IsCancelled=0 " +
                             "inner join MasterFile FM on FM.FileID = FD.FileID and FM.Cancel = 0 " +
                             "inner join Sectors Sec on Sec.Phase_ID = FM.PhaseId and Sec.Sector_ID = FM.Sector_ID " +
                             "left join PlotsInventory I on I.Phase_ID = FM.PhaseId and I.Plot_ID = FM.Plot_ID " +
                             "inner join Phases P on P.Phase_ID = FM.PhaseId " +
                             "inner join ReferencePerson RP on RP.RPersonID = FM.RPersonID " +
                             "where MM.MemberShipID = '" + MemberShipID + "'", con);
                }


                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable mdt_Member = new DataTable();
                    ad.Fill(mdt_Member);

                    for (int i = 0; i < mdt_Member.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        obj_ownership = new OwnerShip();
                        obj_ownership.FileId = mdt_Member.Rows[i]["FileId"].ToString();
                        if (mdt_Member.Rows[i]["TransDate"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {

                            obj_ownership.TransDate = DateTime.Parse(mdt_Member.Rows[i]["TransDate"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        }
                        else
                            obj_ownership.TransDate = string.Empty;

                        obj_ownership.Project = mdt_Member.Rows[i]["Project"].ToString();
                        obj_ownership.UnitNo = mdt_Member.Rows[i]["UnitNo"].ToString();
                        obj_ownership.RpersonName = mdt_Member.Rows[i]["RpersonName"].ToString();


                        OwnerShipDetail.Add(obj_ownership);
                        ViewBag.objOwnershipDetail = OwnerShipDetail;
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                return Json(OwnerShipDetail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Grid

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $.noConflict();
        var rowsToColor = [];
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var $grid = $("#jqGrid");
            $grid.jqGrid({
                url: '@Url.Action("Ownership_D")',
                datatype: 'json',
                postData: { MemberShipID: function () { return $("#mID").val(); } },
                jsonReader: { id: 'FileID' },
                colModel: [
                           { name: 'FileId', index: 'FileId', label: 'File Id', width:3 },
                           { name: 'UnitNo', index: 'UnitNo', label: 'Unit No', width:7 },
                           { name: 'TransDate', index: 'TransDate', label: 'Trans Date', width:8},
                           { name: 'RpersonName', index: 'RpersonName', label: 'File Category', width: 10 },
                           { name: 'Project', index: 'Project', label: 'Project', width: 20 }
                ],
                additionalProperties: [],
                loadonce: true,
                navOptions: {
                    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
                },
                formEditing: {

                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    closeAfterEdit: true,
                    savekey: [true, 13],
                    reloadGridOptions: {

                        fromServer: true
                    }
                },
                viewrecords: true,
                height: 400,
                autowidth:true,
                rowNum: 100,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 500],
                pager: "#jqGridPager",
                rownumbers: true,
                footerrow: true,
                sortname: "Name",
                sortorder: "desc"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but it looks like your code may be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack via `MemberShipID`, you should fix that by using parameterized SQL.  See [How does the SQL injection from the “Bobby Tables” XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/3744182) for a general discussion, and [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/3744182) and (e.g.) [What is the correct way to form a parameterized SQL statement in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18900579/3744182) for .Net specifics.

Comment: Thanks for reply

Comment: Well if you're just trying to return the JSON, why are you using a view at all? What does your view do? I'd normally expect a view to return a rendered view of the model data, e.g. in HTML. While it would be *possible* to write a view that converted model data from one format into JSON, it would be unusual.